# Send IR values using infrared emitter led on Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors, infrared

i have [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) and an IR Emitting LED and i want to send data **"Hex Data"** that i choose using this LED and i have tried the [IRRemote Library](https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote) and i have successfully used the `IRrecv` class, but when using `IRsend` i didn't get any signal and have tried to look at the led through the mobile camera
the IR Emitter Pin is **PWM 3** and have connected it to **3.3V** once and to **5V** once

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.read() != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12); // Sony TV power code
      delay(40);
    }
  }
}
```

and for the receiver:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated :) **Hiso**

Comment: What type of IR receiver are you using?

Comment: @WernerVesterås this is the datasheet http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/file/view/IR-Receiver-AX-1838HS.pdf

Comment: According to the troubleshooting guide, the LED on pin 13 (the onboard LED) will blink when IR is received.  Does this happen?

Comment: @WernerVesterås when i use the receive example alone the light blinks but when combing the two examples together the LED stops blinking

Comment: This could hardware problem. Try changing the LED and check if it is the same PWM pin used in the library. You may also want to increase the delay to 100 from 40 as per example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i Have looked at the **IRRemote.cpp** library you refereed to and in the header file you can see that each Arduino board have a unique `PWM` pin that is used to transmit infrared data so use `PWM 9` it's assured to work on Arduino Mega